# Is it compliant to use a webgl canvas as a texture

Tags: webgl

I have a WEBGL program running on "CanvasA" and I am trying to use "CanvasA" as a texture for a separate program running on "CanvasB".

Looking at [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D) it appears this can be done by supplying "CanvasA" as the final parameter of the "gl.texImage2D" function.

```
void gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalformat, format, type, HTMLCanvasElement? pixels);
```

So I tried doing that, and it works in Chrome & Firefox, Hooray!

However it only shows a blank texture on IOS Safari and Microsoft Edge.

Neither of the latter browsers have any errors in the console, and everything else seems to work. "CanvasA" shows what it should, and the rest of "CanvasB" looks correct, ignoring the blank texture.

The texture on "CanvasB" has it's filtering set to "NEAREST" and no mipmap's are being generated. Also I am using WEBGL 1.

Is this behavior expected? As in are not all browsers required to support using a WEBGL canvas as a texture, or are there any settings I should look for that may be causing the problem?

Comment: Is [`preserveDrawingBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) set to true for CanvasA ?

Comment: @LJᛃ Nope, but turning it on solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: That suggests you weren't calling `gl.texImage2D` with the same event that canvasA was rendered to.